# Process Builder - Slack Message Sends Before Previous Actions Finish Executing

Tags: process-builder

I created a flow in Process Builder that adds text to a certain text field, should criteria be met.

This works well, and the text field is updating as intended when an Opportunity is created.

I set an additional action to send a Slack message to our organization from this flow.  I want to include the text field that updates previously in the flow in this Slack message.

What seems to be happening is the Slack message sends before the above actions complete, which causes the text field that appears in the Slack message to not reflect its true value.

***EX:***

- An Opp is created with info for MED and info for PERS.
- Per the workflow, if MED criteria are met, the text field updates to current_text_field_value(null)+ " MED"
- Then, the workflow continues, and if PERS criteria are met, the text field updates to current_text_field_value(now " Med") + " PERS"
- This results in the final value of the text field reading " MED PERS" - This is what I want to happen.
- The last step in the flow is to send a Slack message that includes the text field. The Slack message should contain " MED PERS".  However, what's happening is it's only sending " MED", and seems like it isn't waiting for the previous action (adding + " PERS" to the text field) to complete before sending the message.

How can I update the flow to not send the Slack message until all of the actions above it are fully executed?

Here is a sample of the flow:

[image]

Comment: if you look at the debug log; do you see the Update Record action DML occurring before the invocable Apex action?  If not, then you'll need to use a "signal" field and a re-evaluation of the PB to get the last decision block to realize all is ready. However, it is much easier to just convert this to a Flow as the proceduralism you desire is more transparent

Comment: I do think converting to a flow should help me in this situation. Thanks!